# Number of ways of putting n identical objects into s boxes,if one box can only fit n/2 at most.

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways of putting N objects into S boxes are there considering that one box can fit N/2 objects at most.
When researching i came across these two solutions:

$\left(\begin{array}{c}N+S-1\\ S-1\end{array}\right)$
And
$\left(\begin{array}{c}N-1\\ S-1\end{array}\right)$
But unfortunately neither gave the right answer for N=4 and S=3.

Comment: What have you tried?  Hint: if you ignore the constraint, what is the answer?  Now try to count the unconstrained solutions that violate the constraint.

Comment: Between this and [your prior question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2905332/how-many-ways-of-putting-4-distinct-pens-in-3-identical-boxes-are-there) it really looks like you are jsut posting your homework here for us to do for you.  Please edit your post to show your efforts.  What have you tried? Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: Your two expressions look like a *stars and bars* calculation for particular forms of this question without the constraint

Comment: @lulu i posted the to formulae i found and tried out,i don't know the solution so it can be inferred that there is not much i could have tried.

Comment: @Henry yes,but the result they give is even less than the answer to the problem With constraints.